# CSS box shadow around triangle

Tags: html, css, shadow

I need to create a triangle with a drop shadow using simple html and css.  Answered by another stackoverflow question, I was able to create the triangle with mitered borders.  Basically I create 1 side of a box with a very wide border and the nearby side with a wide transparent border:

```
div.triangle {
    border-bottom : 60px solid transparent;
    border-left : 60px solid black;
}
```

works great, but when I try to apply a box-shadow the shadow goes around the enclosing square... not the triangle:

```
div.triangle {
    border-bottom : 60px solid transparent;
    border-left : 60px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

How do I get a triangle using only css/html with a drop shadow?

Comment: My suggestion: Use an image. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @Drackir, I'm hoping I don't have to...

Comment: Well, it would be simpler and cross browser compatible. :)

Comment: `img` or `canvas` is probably easier, but if you want to keep trying things, you might do that quarter round thing plus a partially rotated `div` over top the curved edge. Then you'll have hack upon hack but no image or canvas

Comment: @Michael Haren, partially rotated `div`?  How does that work?

Comment: This is not impossible Look at my answer.

Comment: @inquisitive, I replied to your answer.  The problem is I just can't get a decent shadow that way (more importantly it doesn't match the shadows of the surrounding elements in my site).

Comment: I hope this helps... It's all I can come up with if it doesn't I would suggest using a canvas or image. http://jsfiddle.net/5dw8M/117/

Comment: @inquisitive, I don't understand that example

Comment: Can you post an image of the rendering you're hoping for? Different techniques apply to slightly different cases.

Comment: You could try `text-shadow` and use a Unicode  arrow ◀ ▲ ▶▼. You can use CSS `transform: scale(x, y)` to change the width and height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like impossible. Definitely using an imagine is much more easier solution.
I've made something like triangle :) http://jsfiddle.net/5dw8M/109/ . Sorry cannot leave a comment under your post. May be it'll serve like an inspiration for someone;

Comment: Your triangle is really a quarter circle... for my purposes I can't use that.

Comment: I created something based off this answer, so I'm giving you credit for this

Comment: @at: what did you do? I'd be interested to know.

Comment: I made the curved part longer using a horizontal radius of 50% and vertical radius of 100%, makes it look straighter... though still not nearly good enough... just a temporary measure.

Answer (score 4):

What about put another div with similar property and play with positions?
something like http://jsfiddle.net/eveevans/JWGTw/

Comment: The problem there is the drop shadow will have to be completely sharp, there's not fuzziness to the shadow at all.

Comment: This worked for me, bit of a hack but at least i can have a transparent shadow now. images just can't do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "transform" property to rotate a square 45 degrees and hide half of it, but not all browsers support it, so you'll need a fallback.

```
.triangle-with-shadow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #999;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
   -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
   top: 25px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}​
```

[Demo on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bossy_nova/wBUW7/1/)

Lifted from [this CSS Tricks page](http://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/) with modifications.

Comment: but you can edit the triangle's height with this solution. this is just for equilateral triangle.

Comment: @yosafatade You could try `scale(2, 1)` for example to stretch the triangle...?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best option is using `filter`:

```css
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would `<canvas>` with a PNG fallback be an option?

Demo: [**jsfiddle.net/Marcel/3dbzm/1**](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/3dbzm/1/)

Comment: I didn't want to use canvas, but it looks like this may be my only option.

Answer (score 1):

Create a duplicate of that triangle, decolorize it, give it a negative z-index value using css, and finally off center it with CSS positioning.

```
div.triangle {
z-index:-1;
position:relative;
bottom:-16px;
right:-16px;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as eveevans' answer?