# triangle with shadow using css

Tags: html, css

#### CSS

```
.caret-bottom
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align:top;
    content: "";
    border-top: 9px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent; 
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 4px;   
  }
```

#### HTML CODE

```
<div class="caret-left"></div>
```

I need shadow bottom side for this triangle like a 3D effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332366/css-box-shadow-around-triangle?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.triangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.triangle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 75px;
  left: 25px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/w9Zgc/

Answer (score 1):

Hi post is a bit old but have an example that I used. 
Link to [demo](http://codepen.io/wolendranh/pen/NNJKoN) with code.

```css
.triangle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: left;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.triangle,
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  border-top-right-radius: 30%;
}
.triangle {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1, .866);
}
.triangle:before {
  transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414, .707) translate(0, -50%);
}
.triangle:after {
  transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707, 1.414) translate(50%);
}
.triangle {
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 7px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0));
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 7px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="triangle-wrap">
    <div class='triangle'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one i think it will help you

```css
.caret-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  border-top: 10px solid #fff;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
}
.caret-bottom:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  border-top: 10px solid #000;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -12px;
  left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="caret-bottom"></div>
```