# How to Add Box Shadow Effect To Pseudo After Content

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can add Box-shadow to  Pseudo After Content? as you can see I tried to add like

```
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
```

but it is not adding the shadow and instead creating  a box

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  background: #eee;
 }

.hero {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 320px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.hero:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 40px #fff;
  border-left: solid 40px transparent;
  border-right: solid 40px transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: It's the expected behavior, a box shadow is rectangular. What you could do is drawing a square and then, rotate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS box shadow around triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332366/css-box-shadow-around-triangle)

Answer (score 3):

I think This Code will help you.

I have added properties: `transform-origin` and `box-sizing`

**For reference:** [transform-origin](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) and [box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

```css
body {
  background-color: #888;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #bada55;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.hero::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  bottom: -2em;
  left: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1em solid black;
  border-color: transparent transparent #bada55 #bada55;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for upvoting :) . I will add the needed explanation .

Answer (score 1):

Deleted all the shadows and added container with property `filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2));` which creates shadow by shape.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  background: #eee;
 }
 
.container {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2));
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 320px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.hero:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 40px #fff;
  border-left: solid 40px transparent;
  border-right: solid 40px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="hero"></div>
</div>
```